# How to unrar every file in a directory to its correspondent folder?

Tags: rar

I have a directory full of *.rar files and I want each of them to be extracted to a folder with the same name as its .rar correspondent, but i do not want to use for loops. How can i do that ?

I'm on Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you don't want to use loops for your problem?

Comment: when i do not use for loops, E.g.(unrar x '*'), unrar shows me just one output, and this output contains the total number of files that where extracted, which are corrupted and which aren't, when i use for loops, unrar shows me a lot of outputs, each one taking in account just a single file, and i do not want to scan the whole for loop's output for errors

Comment: What about while loops ? Or iterators ?

Comment: also no, i want a behavior similar to (unrar x '*'). Some .rar files when extracted with the 'x' option, will have its own directory, which is good, some will be extracted to the current directory, which i do not want by any means to happen.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use *unrar* on Ubuntu by installing it with `sudo apt-get install unrar`.

After that, you'll have to create a for loop in order to extract the files separately without wanting them to combine into one folder.

You can achieve this regularly with: `for f in *.rar; do unrar e “$f”; done`.

If you want to log any type of error, you can always create a simple script where you create a loop, and inside the loop, you'll write or output anything to a specific file.

Comment: thank you for you response, but.... did you read carefully my question ?

Comment: i do not want to use for loops

Comment: You can use one single command like `unrar e -r *.rar` to extract all .rar files, but the files end up in your current directory. If you want them to be extracted in a directory with the same name as the file you'll have to use a for-loop in order to use the correct parameters for extracting. If you care about logging or error handling, you can achieve that with a simple script.

Answer (score 0):

There's a package in Ubuntu called [`unar`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/unar.1.html), which does what you want.

The -d switch is the helpful one

> `-d, -force-directory`
> Always  create a containing directory for the contents of the unpacked archive.  By default, a directory is created if there is more than one top-level file or folder.

So something like `unar -d *.rar *` should do the trick.